# How can I put numbers In a column from left to right?

Tags: java

My assignment is to using loops output this

> 1 2 3 4 5 6
>
> 2 3 4 5 6 7
>
> 3 4 5 6 7 8
>
> 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> 5 6 7 8 9 10

As of now my program

```
public class Assigment10 

{

public static void main(String[] args) 

{
        for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++)

{


System.out.print(i + "  ");
    }

        for(int i = 2; i < 8; i++)
    {       
        System.out.print(i + "  ");
    }

        for(int i = 3; i < 9; i++)
    {       
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }

        for(int i = 4; i < 10; i++)
    {       
        System.out.print(i + "  ");
    }
        for(int i = 5; i < 11; i++)
    {       
        System.out.print(i + "  ");
    }



}
}
```

Outputs 1 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 6 7 Ect, using \r \n gives me vertical positions for the numbers is there a way to get the orientation I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `System.out.println();` after each loop except the last one.

```
public class Assigment10 {

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 2; i < 8; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 3; i < 9; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 4; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 5; i < 11; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + "  ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Or including the last one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
    k=1;
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)  {
     for(int j = k; j < k+6; j++) {
       System.out.print(j +" ");
     }
     System.out.println("");
     k=k+1;
    }
```

Comment: `k` is always equal to `i`, so why not just use `i`?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by using a single nested loop (instead of five loops that differ only by one in start and end conditions). Next, it's unclear if you want your numbers **left aligned** *or* **right aligned** in the columns. For **left alignment** you might do something like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int start = i + 1;
    int end = start + 6;
    for (int j = start; j < end; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

And for **right alignment**, you could use `System.out.printf` in the inner loop like

```
for (int j = start; j < end; j++) {
    System.out.printf("%2d ", j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be to put `System.out.println();` after every for loop because it just inserts a blank line

```
for(int i = 2; i < 8; i++)
    {       
        System.out.print(i + "  ");
    }
System.out.println();
        for(int i = 3; i < 9; i++)
    {       
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
System.out.println();
        for(int i = 4; i < 10; i++)
    {       
        System.out.print(i + "  ");
    }
System.out.println();
        for(int i = 5; i < 11; i++)
    {       
        System.out.print(i + "  ");
    }
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=1; i<6; i++) {
    for (int j=i; j<i+6; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + " "));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have used an embedded loop (loop within loop)
here is solution by putting your values in an array

```
public class Exercise {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int [] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
       int start=0;
       int finish =6;
      for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
       for(int i=start; i<finish; i++){
           System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
       }
       System.out.println("");
       start++;
       finish++;
      }        
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using embedded loops to make code concise.

```
public class Answer {
public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i=1; i<6; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
            System.out.print((i+j) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}